# Subset dataframe based on matches with list

Tags: r

I want to subset `distal.results.stratified.model.1` dataframe if the `probeID` column matches one of the `cg*` items in the `coMeth_ls` list. My code returned empty dataframe.

```
distal.dmr.cpgs.1a <- distal.results.stratified.model.1a[
  sapply(
    strsplit(distal.results.stratified.model.1a$probeID, ' '), 
    function(x) any(x %in% coMeth_ls)), ]
```

Data:

```
> dput(distal.results.stratified.model.1a[1:3,1:3])
structure(list(regionID = c("chr1:1355332-1355333", "chr1:15934516-15934517", 
"chr1:15934516-15934517"), probeID = c("cg03324138", "cg01522970", 
"cg01522970"), target = c("ENSG00000162576", "ENSG00000065526", 
"ENSG00000065526")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(coMeth_ls[1:10])
list(`chr1:2250410-2250796` = c("cg03324138", "cg02237208", "cg00567930"
), `chr1:2886792-2886868` = c("cg01977798", "cg00050294", "cg04080530"
), `chr1:8271997-8272277` = c("cg02847588", "cg00590817", "cg06780032"
), `chr1:10895950-10896004` = c("cg02971581", "cg09510180", "cg00944431"
), `chr1:12600225-12600529` = c("cg07586026", "cg07242540", "cg00003578"
), `chr1:16553267-16553456` = c("cg03969515", "cg03522107", "cg02987928"
), `chr1:19665131-19665240` = c("cg09356672", "cg05348366", "cg04928049"
), `chr1:23003462-23003569` = c("cg01795776", "cg09062638", "cg02623028"
), `chr1:28573736-28573940` = c("cg05045517", "cg03226554", "cg07148744", 
"cg07913096"), `chr1:29460817-29461070` = c("cg06155303", "cg09264065", 
"cg08597839", "cg00107241"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you want, but if you want to select the rows of `distal.results.stratified.model.1a` where `probeID` matches any of the sub-elements of the list `coMeth_ls` then use:

```
distal.results.stratified.model.1a[
  distal.results.stratified.model.1a$probeID %in% unlist(coMeth_ls), ]

              regionID    probeID          target
1 chr1:1355332-1355333 cg03324138 ENSG00000162576
```